# LibGDX Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.f

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I get this problem in google play console but not in ide anymore(I use intelij).

I suspect there may be a problem with proguard.

Here is my proguard:

```
-verbose

-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication

# Required if using Gdx-Controllers extension
-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.**{
   **[] $VALUES;
    *;
}

-keep class com.your.game.data.**{
   **[] $VALUES;
    *;
}

# Required if using Box2D extension
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

Comment: I would say the class you use extends another class and you must pass arguments to the super() in /or from a constructor at minimum whether they are literals fed inside a no Arg constructor to super(....the args....)   or the class you built obtains some or all the args to feed to super(....args...)

Comment: The library in question is built into the framework I'm using (LibGDX) and I don't seem to be able to add a super() to it anywhere or I just don't know where to

Comment: I'll just presume "you" have written main class to import the library into, you would be "extending"? from a class in LibGDX ? Or is there a problem with pre loading LibGDX from some ready made program configuration on startup?

Comment: It appears you did not initialise a class you needed from this package is the most probable e.g. there is a variable but no construction call in the code, or it is in an if else (or some block) and unclear to the compiler if it would  get called.
     com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui

Comment: However, starting an android application uses a no Arg constructor and is as I mentioned before "extended" class, so for main class it does no harm to put in public MyMainClass(){super();}